# ¿Como obtengo el valor mas alto en un hash de Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tengo este hash,

```
meses_ventas = {'Enero' => 2000, 'Febrero' => 3000, 'Marzo' => 1000, 'Abril' => 5000, 'Mayo' => 4000}
```

Y necesito obtener el valor mas alto entre todos los valores.
Resulta que intento iterarlo con each, pero no logro hacer que el valor mas alto del hash osea el 5000 del mes de Abril se almacene en una variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo necesitas obtener el valor más alto del hash (`5000`), lo mejor que puedes hacer es trabajar directamente con lo valores en vez de los pares clave-valor.

```
meses_ventas.values.max
# => 5000
```

`values` regresa un Array con todos los valores, y como en tu caso todos los `values` o pares son números (`Integer`), puedes utilizar el método `max` que regresa el objeto con el `max`imo valor.

Importante notar que el método `max` regresaría un error (`ArgumentError`) si tuvieras `Integer`s y `String`s combinados en los valores.

Saludos.

Comment: esta respuesta es mejor.

Comment: Necesito tambíen que me muestre el nombre del producto, o sea el key

Comment: Entonces lo más correcto es trabajar con el método `max_by` como comentó @Horacio: `meses_ventas.max_by { |k,v| v } # => ["Abril", 5000]`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `max_by` que te va a regresar un array parecido a este: `[llave, par]`. Después llama únicamente el último elemento del array.

```
meses_ventas.max_by{ |llave, par| par }[-1]
# => 5000
```

Lo puedes 'leer' de la siguiente forma:

Al hash `meses_ventas` aplica `max_by` con los argumentos `llave` y `par`, y después regresa el que tenga el `par` mayor. Sólo llamamos `par`, pero como es `max_by`, sabemos que será el `par` mayor.

Finalmente, lo que regresa es un Array, en dónde el primer objeto es la `llave` y el último es el `par`. El `[-1]` se encarga de regresar el último elemento del array `['Abril', 5000]`, es decir, `5000`.